# Java audio synthesis library that can be used for coding Android apps

Tags: android, java, audio

I'm looking for a Java audio synthesis library that can be used for coding Android apps. It should be able to do the basic stuff, like:

- Tone generation in the four basic waveforms: sine, triangle, square, and sawtooth.
- Equalization.
- Processes like reverb, compression, delay, etc. (not required, but a good extra to have)

Which are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [LibPD](http://libpd.cc/), which lets you call [Pure Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_Data) from Java and other programming languages.

> libpd is Pure Data. It is not a fork of Pure Data, not a different flavor of Pure Data. It is simply a way of using Pd in a new way that can be more convenient and allows compatibility with mobile app development, game development, embedding into sophisticated 3D visualization tools, and lots of other applications. As such, it adds to Pd, without taking away anything from Pd Vanilla’s DSP core. It has the same license as Pd, too. It is every bit as free and open source as Pd. As such, the project is hugely indebted to the entire Pd community, and to Pd’s original creator, Miller Puckette. Those of us working with libpd have done so because we’re excited to see Pd patches running in more places than ever before, doing things they’ve never done before, and we trust you’re just getting started.